# How do I use different queries based on parameter value

Tags: reporting-services

(1).In my ssrs report I have 2 queries which i need to put in my dataset.
Based on a dropdown parameter I want to select which query to run.
Is it Possible to do so? Please, help me out.

Ex.
I

```
If (Parameters!sFlag.Value == "0")
{ Query1}
else
{Query2}
```

(2).Also based on same parameter i want to select fields in a textbox.

Ex.
=I

```
If(Fields!IsFlag.Value="0" , Fields!Field3.Value, Fields!Field18.Value)
```

I am using Informix .

I searched a lot but couldnt find anything appropriate as this thing I have done with sql query but when I apply the same with Informix it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both queries return the same fields and use the same connection then you could union them together using the parameter to control which returns data. I know that the MSSQL optimiser will effectively not bother running the non true half of the query, not sure about Informix. The result is that you get the values from the first query when the sFlag parameter is "0" and from the second query when its "1".

SELECT 1 as Value WHERE @sFlag = “0”

UNION ALL

SELECT 2 as Value WHERE @sFlag = “1”